# Apache Maven ServiceMix not starting in mac?

Tags: maven, apache-servicemix

When i try to run the 'maven servicemix' it throws following error.

To run i used following command:

```
.\bin\servicemix
```

Error:

```
jdk1.7.0_71/bin/java: cannot execute binary file
```

Any idea how to run maven service mix?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution by adding 'sudo' permission, run as follows in terminal.

1. Go inside the service mix folder:

   ***cd /apache-servicemix-7.0.0.M1/***
2. Provide 'sudo' permission:

   ***sudo ./bin/servicemix***
3. Done!